# My component is never read, in my React code

Tags: reactjs

Component, myImage is never read.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import myImage from './Profile/Profile.myImage';

const HomeProfile = () => {
    return (
        <Box sx={{ border: '1px dashed grey' }}>
            <myImage />
            <Link to="/app/profile" className="red btn-flat white-text">
                Change Profile
            </Link>
        </Box>
    )
}

export default HomeProfile;
```

This is the file './Profile/Profile.myImage':

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchProfile } from '../../../actions';
import { Image } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';

class myImage extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchProfile();
    }

    async renderMyImage() {
        const imageDir = await axios.get('/api/profile');

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>hello</h1>
                <Image src={imageDir.profileImg.type} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.renderMyImage()}</div>
                <h1>bye</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


function mapStateToProps({ user }) {
    return { user };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchProfile})(myImage);
```

In the route.js, app.get('/api/profile') is defined like this.
however, nothing appears in the console.

```
app.get('/api/profile', requireLogin, async(req, res) => {
        console.log('test: api/profile');
        const profile = await User.find({ _user: req.user.id });

        res.send(profile);
    })
```

I thought, something was wrong in the function 'renderMyImage()', so I added "hello" and "bye", but still, nothing is on the view, while other components can be seen on the screen.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: There is no error in the console...

Answer (score 1):

axios is async so renderMyImage should be an async function.
Have you tried

```
async renderMyImage() {
    const imageDir = await axios.get('/api/profile');

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hello</h1>
            <Image src={imageDir.profileImg.type} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the mistake of async await. 
I added now, but still does not appear.

Comment: have you configured axios properly with the right base url?

Comment: I did, in the setupProxy.js.
Also, the other axios request worked, so I'm very confused.

Comment: I'm confused too, you write that console.log() doesn't work in your route '/api/profile', but that the request work 